# Por qué no se instala el SDK Android 8.0 en Android Studio?

Tags: android

Todo iba bien hasta que me salió una nueva actualización de Android y la descargue, cuando se termina de instalar me sale el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le doy en "Install mussing platform(s) and sync project" y se empieza a descargar el SDK pero luego que finaliza no me soluciona nada pues me sigue saliendo el mismo error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, trato de descargar el SDK Android 8.0 y aunque igualmente dice que se descarga e instala, luego sigue saliendo como que nada se ha descargado ni instalado. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual sucede con la pestaña de SDK tools. No se ya que hacer porque no me sale ningún error en la descarga.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esto indica el mensaje de error:

> Install missing platform(s) and sync Project

no tienes instalada la plataforma para la versión 8.0 u 8.1, incluso para ninguna versión, debes instalar al menos las que indica tu proyecto veo que son la 23 (Android 6.0) y 26 (Android 8.0) por lo que debes instalarlas.

Seleccionalas y da click en ok para que se instalen y puedas construir tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si las instalas pero continúan sin aparecer entonces **el problema es que no tienes permisos en tu pc para instalar**, lo comento porque veo usas un usuario "genérico".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intente volver a descargarlo pero me sale igual, dice que se instala pero luego no me sale. No se como verificar lo que me dice de que no tengo permiso para instalar, ejecute Android Studio como administrador  e intento instalar pero igual me sigue dando el error.